# Is there a shorter replacement for Kotlin's deprecated String.capitalize() function?

Tags: string, kotlin, deprecated, capitalization

Kotlin deprecated the `capitalize` function on `String` class, and their suggested replacement is obnoxiously long.  This is an example of a situation where they made the right call on deprecating it, but the wrong call on the user experience.

For example, this code:

```
val x = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz").map { it.capitalize() }
```

is "cleaned up" by the IDE to become:

```
val x = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz").map { it.replaceFirstChar {
                    if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(
                        Locale.getDefault()
                    ) else it.toString()
                } }
```

This is preeeeetty ugly.  What can we do about it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The suggested replacement is ugly because it needs to be equivalent to what `capitalize()` used to do:

1. dependent on the default locale
2. NOT converting an uppercase first char into titlecase (e.g.
   `capitalize` does NOT transform a leading 'Ǆ' into 'ǅ' - both are single characters here, try to select them)

If you didn't care too much about this behaviour, you can use a simpler expression using an invariant locale and unconditionally titlecasing the first character even if uppercase:

```kotlin
val x = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz").map { it.replaceFirstChar(Char::titlecase) }
```

This means that if the first character is uppercase like `'Ǆ'`, it will be transformed into the titlecase variant `'ǅ'` anyway, while the original code wouldn't touch it. This might actually be desirable.

One of the reasons `capitalize()` has been deprecated is because the behaviour of the method was unclear. For instance:

- behaviour #2 is pretty weird
- not capitalizing words in a sentence might be unexpected (C# would titlecase every space-separated word)
- not lowercasing other characters of the words might be unexpected as well

If you want to keep the exact current behaviour on purpose, but make it more convenient to use, you can always roll your own extension function with a name that suits you ("capitalize(d)" might not give enough info to the unaware reader):

```kotlin
fun String.titlecaseFirstCharIfItIsLowercase() = replaceFirstChar { 
    if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() 
}
```

Or for the version with invariant locale that titlecases the uppercase chars:

```kotlin
fun String.titlecaseFirstChar() = replaceFirstChar(Char::titlecase)
```

Comment: Maybe slightly less verbose? `map { it.replaceFirstChar(Char::uppercase) }`

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Good point, that's a neater way of avoiding the shadowing of `it`. I added that to my answer.

Comment: Note: the title case part is there in the suggested replacement for a reason. For example: the character ǆ in title case is ǅ instead of the upper case Ǆ.

Comment: Yes, I clarified my answer to explain what exactly you're giving up.

Comment: This `if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString()` is actually suggested in deprecation note of `capitalize()` and still not the right solution. Imagine this simple case `BAku` Kotlin's suggestion will leave it as is. However, capitalizing means making the word's "first character" uppercase and the rest lowercase. `capitalize()` was an ugly solution and their new suggestion is yet another ugly suggestion. TBH, would have been much better if they didn't suggest anything at all instead of a misleading solution

Comment: @Farid I'm not entirely sure which point you're making here. *`capitalize()` was an ugly solution* - a solution to what problem? `capitalize` was a stdlib function, and is now deprecated because its behaviour was unclear to many users (including you apparently). Yes the replacement I'm mentioning is the one suggested by the deprecation message, that's kinda the point of this answer: either change the behaviour to something simpler because it didn't make sense in the first place, or keep the exact same weird behaviour but wrap it in an extension

Comment: An ugly solution for cases like `BAku`, `appLE`. With `capitalize()` (from Kotlin), one would expect these words to be transformed to `Baku`, `Apple`. Instead, they would end up being `BAku`, `AppLE`, with the replacement they suggest the same thing will happen. This is what I was calling an ugly solution

Comment: @Farid ok. What you mention is exactly the reason why the Kotlin team deprecated this method. With such name, people may expect the behaviour you are describing, or even something else. The current behaviour of `capitalize()` could not be changed for compatibility reasons, so the best way forward is to deprecate and remove the method, and maybe later re-introduce something that match user expectations better. The suggested replacement with the deprecation message is meant to provide the exact same behaviour so people migrating don't have breaking changes, so that's totally expected.

Answer (score 42):

A neat solution is to define a new extension function on String, which hides the gory details with a cleaner name:

```
/**
 * Replacement for Kotlin's deprecated `capitalize()` function.
 */
fun String.capitalized(): String {
    return this.replaceFirstChar { 
        if (it.isLowerCase())
            it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault())
        else it.toString() 
    }
}
```

Now your old code can look like this:

```
val x = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz").map { it.capitalized() }
```

You'll need to define the extension function at the top level in some package that you can import easily.  For example, if you have a kotlin file called `my.package.KotlinUtils` (`KotlinUtils.kt`), and you put the definition inside it like so:

```
package my.package

fun String.capitalized(): String {...}
```

Then you can import it in your other packages with:

```
import my.package.capitalized
```

Comment: I can see a big difference between the correct answer and this one. This must be the recommend answer for anyone whose looking for a right and appropriate usage of Kotlin pure functions. map function is an overkill for few strings to transform. it would increase the overhead performance.

Comment: Or just "fun String.capitalized(): String = this.replaceFirstChar { it.titlecase() }". Calling "titlecase" on a single char is... uhm... and interesting concept. Same calling "toString" on a char without a reason.

Comment: @Lutosław This is how the `titlecase()` function is designed (it's defined on `Char`): a single char can be capitalized with multiple characters, so `Char.titlecase()` returns a `String`. If you use this `if` to check for lowercase before performing any string transformation, you need an else branch that returns a `String`, so... you need `toString()`. It's not without a reason.

Answer (score 8):

```
val fruits = listOf("baNana", "avocAdo", "apPle", "kiwifRuit")
fruits
    .filter { it.startsWith("a") }
    .sortedBy { it }
    .map { it.lowercase().replaceFirstChar(Char::uppercase) }
    .forEach { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
Apple
Avocado
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call the replaceFirstChar function on the original string and pass the transform function as input. The transform function takes the first character and converts it to an uppercase character using the uppercase() function.

```
val list = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz") .map {
     it.replaceFirstChar { firstChar ->
          firstChar.uppercase()
     }
 }
println("List - > $list")
```

Output

```
List - > [Foo, Bar, Baz]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a method trying to capitalize a string that came from the API and it apparently worked, found it in the Kotlin docs:

```
println("kotlin".replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }) // Kotlin
```

and use it like this in my code:

```
 binding.textDescriptions.text = "${it.Year} - ${it.Type.replaceFirstChar {it.uppercase()}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
fun main() {
    val x = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz").map { it[0].uppercase() + it.drop(1) }
    println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
[Foo, Bar, Baz]
```

Comment: Note this will fail if there are empty strings. In that case Joffrey's answer is better.

Comment: To be honest I prefer `replaceFirstChar` not only because it handles empty strings but also because it reflects the intent better.

Comment: My solution uses the exact code proposed by IntelliJ, which I assume they evaluated carefully to ensure that it has the same semantics as the deprecated version of capitalize().

Comment: @stevey. Great. But you asked for a shorter replacement, which is what this is. 

Comment: @AdamMillerchip You got me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure (maybe you receive Strings from an API) if the first letter is upper or lower case , you can use the below method;

```
var title = "myTitle"
title.replaceFirstChar {
        if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else 
        it.toString()
    }
```

New title will be "MyTitle"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension function to capitalize first characture of String

```
fun String.capitalize(): String {
        return this.replaceFirstChar {
            if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault())
            else it.toString()
        }
}
```

And call this method like

```
"abcd".capitalize()
```