# Need explanation of the short Kotlin solution for strings in Codewars

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I got a task on code wars.

**The task is**

In this simple Kata your task is to create a function that turns a string into a Mexican Wave. You will be passed a string and you must return that string in an array where an uppercase letter is a person standing up.

**Rules are**

1. The input string will always be lower case but maybe empty.
2. If the character in the string is whitespace then pass over it as if it was an empty seat

**Example**

wave("hello") => []string{"Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"}

So I have found the solution but I want to understand the logic of it. Since its so minimalistic and looks cool but I don't understand what happens there. So the solution is

```
fun wave(str: String) = str.indices.map { str.take(it) + str.drop(it).capitalize() }.filter { it != str }
```

Could you please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str.indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/indices.html) just returns the valid indices of the string. This means the numbers from 0 to and including `str.length - 1` - a total of `str.length` numbers.

Then, these numbers are `map`ped (in other words, transformed) into strings.  We will now refer to each of these numbers as "`it`", as that is what `it` refers to in the `map` lambda.

Here's how we do the transformation: we first [`take`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html) the first `it` characters of `str`, then combine that with the last `str.length - it` characters of `str`, but with the first of those characters [`capitalize`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html)d. How do we get the last `str.length - it` characters? We [`drop`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop.html) the first `it` characters.

Here's an example for when `str` is "hello", illustrated in a table:

| `it` | `str.take(it)` | `str.drop(it)` | `str.drop(it).capitalize()` | Combined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | hello | Hello | Hello |
| 1 | h | ello | Ello | hEllo |
| 2 | he | llo | Llo | heLlo |
| 3 | hel | lo | Lo | helLo |
| 4 | hell | o | O | hellO |

Lastly, the solution also filters out transformed strings that are the same as `str`. This is to handle Rule #2. Transformed strings can only be the same as `str` if the capitalised character is a whitespace (because capitalising a whitespace character doesn't change it).

Side note: `capitalize` is deprecated. For other ways to capitalise the first character, see [Is there a shorter replacement for Kotlin's deprecated String.capitalize() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843986/is-there-a-shorter-replacement-for-kotlins-deprecated-string-capitalize-funct)

Comment: A table and everything, very nice!

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you please explain one more thing. How this part works `str.take(it) + str.drop(it).capitalize()` . So we I don't understand what happens when `take triggers` and why `+` is there and what characters are capitalized here?

Comment: @BobRedity Please see the table. `take` takes the first `it` characters. `drop` removes the first `it` characters. `+` combines/joins the two parts together. `capitalize()` capitalises the *first* character of `str.drop(it)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could do it:

```
fun wave2(str: String) = str.mapIndexed { i, c -> str.replaceRange(i, i + 1, c.uppercase()) }
    .filter { it.any(Char::isUpperCase) }
```

The filter on the original is way more elegant IMO, this is just as an example of how else you might check for a condition. `replaceRange` is a way to make a copy of a string with some of the characters changed, in this case we're just replacing the one at the current index by uppercasing what's already there. Not as clever as the original, but good to know!