# Kotlin, why is function deprecated?

Tags: kotlin, uppercase

Recently, i've wanted to use **capitalize()** function.
When I did so, a warning occured:

> 'capitalize(): String' is deprecated. Use replaceFirstChar instead.

The suggested **replaceFirstChar** feels quite long and complicated:

> input.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() }

Although everything works fine with **capitalize()**, i've been just wondering what the reason for deprecated warning is, if there's any problem with it and how can i solve this.

Comment: This questions may not actually be a duplicate, but a quick Google search I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843986/is-there-a-shorter-replacement-for-kotlins-deprecated-string-capitalize-funct question and the accepted answer gives a good reason as to why `replaceFirstChar` feels clunky.

Comment: Also if that replacement code works fine for you, you can always use it to create your own `safeCapitalize` (or whatever) function! You can still use `capitalize`, but the fact it's deprecated means at some point it's going to go away, and any code using it will break

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with the code per se. The "issue" is what ***capitalize*** means for all of the possible languages/characters/platforms/locales.

The doc even says why it is deprecated.

> The title case of a character is **USUALLY** the same as its upper case
> with several exceptions. The particular list of characters with the
> special title case form depends on the underlying platform.

If you follow all of the reasoning why it is deprecated you reach [isTitleCase](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-title-case.html) where you will have an example of characters in languages where the character should not be "upper cased".

> Capitalization  is writing a word with its first letter as a capital letter (uppercase
> letter) and the remaining letters in lower case, in writing systems
> with a case distinction.

There are a few good examples and explanations for different languages on *Letter case* [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)
e.g.

> The German letter "ß" formerly existed only in lower case.